# Extract only two matches per unique line and discard more than 3 duplicates

Tags: linux, awk, grep, uniq

I would like to extract names that occur 2 times max. on column 1. If it occurs more than 2 times then I only need to get the first 2.
Eg. 
file1.txt

`10000040 1-120
10000040 541-660
10000040 91-210
10000042 1-120
10000043 541-660
10000048 1-120
10000049 1-120
10000049 181-300
10000049 271-390
10000049 361-480`

From the above file, I want something like this:
`10000040 1-120
10000040 541-660
10000042 1-120
10000043 541-660
10000048 1-120
10000049 1-120
10000049 181-300`

I have tried uniq and -D but they don't give what I want. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What about the `-m` flag? `grep -m 2 '10000040 1-120' yourfile.txt`

Comment: Why does 10000040 only occur once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '++_[$1] < 3' input_file
```

Shortened version of ctac_ answer

Comment: Never name a variable `_` - that's even worse than a single letter name for legibility and adds absolutely zero value, it's only impact is negative.

Comment: I consider it a throw away variable as it is not used any further, but you are entitled to your opinion

Comment: OK but what's the benefit of `_[]` over, say, `a[]` which at least gives you a clue you're dealing with a variable and that it's an array?

Comment: No advantage or disadvantage in my view.  The fact that you prefer to see a letter or word of some kind is a preference.  I have used this format frequently to find unique items in lists, ie so it is just my preference :)

Answer (score 0):

With awk

```
awk '{a[$1]++}a[$1]<3{print}' infile
```

Comment: `'{a[$1]++}a[$1]<3{print}'` = `'++a[$1]<3'`

Comment: Thanks. That worked. @grail 's solution was much shorter and seemed to do the work I wanted.